# How can I load a custom twig template depending on a view mode?

Tags: theming

Currently I have the following code in my module file:

```
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_credit_report(array $variables) {
  return [
    'pdf_report__' . $variables['elements']['#view_mode']
  ];
}

function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'pdf_report' => [
      'render element' => 'elements'
    ]
  ];
}
```

And I have inside /mymodule/templates/ 2 twig files

1. pdf-report.html.twig (just added the code from entity-html.twig)
2. pdf-report--new-style.html.twig

And I have a view mode in my pdf-report called new_style.

I've read documentation and it looks like this should work, but it doesn't.

I tried doing the following:

```
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_credit_report(array $variables) {
  return [
    'pdf_report__' . $variables['elements']['#view_mode']
  ];
}

function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'pdf_report' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template'  => 'pdf-report--orcutt-style',
      'base hook' => 'pdf_report',
    ]
  ];
}
```

But this replaces all of the view modes, not just the one I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the new theme hook is the same as the base hook. You need to declare the more specific theme suggestion as hook:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'pdf_report__new_style' => [
      'base hook' => 'pdf_report',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: It worked!, I can't believe I didn't tried this before, thank you!